# Framer Motion: Conflict with Parent and Children Animations

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

So I just learned framer motion a few days ago and now I hit my first roadblock. I was just going about animating containers and buttons until I stumbled into the following problem:

I was trying to animate the div container with the following variant:

```
const containerVariant = {
  hover: {
    rotateZ: [0, 3, -3, 0],
    transition: {
      yoyo: Infinity,

    }
  }
};
```

As well as a Button with the following variant:

```
const btnHoverVariant = {
  hidden: {
    scale: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    transition: {
      type: "tween",
      duration: 0.25,
      ease: "easeInOut"
    }
  },
  hov: {
    scale: 1.1,
    opacity: 0.8,
    transition: {
      type: "tween",
      duration: 0.25,
      ease: "easeInOut"
    }
  }
};
```

My problem is that when I hover on the container it works (the wiggle effect), but when I hover on the button, the button hover effect(the scale effect) it doesn't work.

I did find a workaround for the problem which is to use object syntax for whileHover, transition, and initial props. But for code modularity, I'd like to use variants so if anyone could help me out with my problem, It would be greatly appreciated!
Here is a snippet of the work around:

```
<motion.button
          initial="{{ scale: 1, opacity: 1 }}"
          whileHover={{ scale: 1.1, opacity: 0.8 }}
          transition={{ type: "tween", duration: 0.25, ease: "easeInOut" }}
          style={btnStyle}
          >
          Click Me!
</motion.button>
```

Here is the code sandbox for both the cases that are mentioned above: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-diffie-0m2mp?file=/src/test.jsx